# sorting a list of dates in a python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort a list of dates in python dictionary. for example if I had dates and names in a dictionary as follows:

```
John 11/09/1998
Tom 02/01/1995
Steve 07/01/1988
Mike 12/12/2001
```

I want them sorted so that the most recent date is first and the oldest date is last i.e.

```
Mike 12/12/2001 # this will be first
Steve 07/01/1988 # this will be last in my above example.
```

from what I have been reading using the code below is the way to go about it. Any of you guys got an example?

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
```

Comment: Is your dates in string format or datetime object ?

Comment: I use `datetime.strptime` but if You have a solution for both I would be interested for future reference.

Comment: 02/01/1995 should be the last(oldest) date right ?

Comment: No the date that is 1988 would be the last date.